# Pygame draw antialiased filled polygon

Tags: python, pygame, polygon, antialiasing

The documentation says "For aapolygon, use aalines with the ‘closed’ parameter.", but pygame.draw.aalines doesn't let me specify the width (0 = filled), making it not fill the surface. This looks just terrible:
[image]

These circles look much better:

[image]

How can I do this?

I generate the surface using quadratic beziers, whose coordinates get appended to a list. Then I draw it onto the surface like this (In the image above I did this twice, once for the outer circle and once for the inner circle):

```
pygame.draw.polygon(self.image,fclr,self.points)
```

And the drawing code (shape.image is the same surface as self.image in the code above):

```
screen.fill((0,0,0))
screen.blit(shape.image,(100,100))
pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: Could you post some code?

Comment: Perhaps you could use `pygame.gfxdraw.aapolygon()` to draw the interior, and `pygame.draw.aalines()` to draw the outline.

Comment: There's gfxdraw.aapolygon and gfxdraw.filled_polygon but no gfxdraw.filled_aapolygon. Haz, what code do you want me to post? The blitting code, the code that generates the surface or something else?

Comment: The blitting code is probably the most important, but it might help to see the code that generates the surface as well.  It might be that the best solution would be to draw a filled polygon and then draw an antialiased polygon around it.

Comment: I edited the question with some code, I'll try the filled polygon with the antialiased polygon around it tomorrow.

Comment: Doesn't work, the colors are different somehow when using gfxdraw and it still doesn't look antialiased.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

martineau's comment is on point: In order to draw antialiased filled shapes with pygame, use the module `gfxdraw` and draw one regular filled shape and one antialiased outline. From http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/gfxdraw.html:

"To draw an anti aliased and filled shape, first use the aa* version of the function, and then use the filled version."

Note that you need to import `gfxdraw` explicitly, i.e. `from pygame import gfxdraw`.

Comment: This question is old and I figured how to do it a long time ago, but that doesn't mean it isn't a good answer, so I accepted it ;) When I posted this question, I thought I had to use one function that does everything instead of drawing to circles on top of eachother.

Comment: I suspected that you'd solved it already. But I thought the answer should be here for the benefit of future lost souls. By the way, note that it is possible to answer your own questions and earn some rep that way ;).

Answer (score 1):

I made some tests and with my pygame version (2.1.2) drawing aapolygons (lines) on top of a polygon (jagged edges) results in jaggies on the right and lower sides because the lines are inside the jagged polygon area. I whipped up a quick test for a workaround function that uses supersampling to convert the jagged polygon into a smooth one. For anyone interested here is the code:

```
def draw_aapolygon(surface, color, points, scale=2):                            
    """                                                                         
    Draw antialiased polygon using supersampling.                               
    """                                                                         
    # Calculate minimum x and y values.                                         
    x_coords = tuple(x for x, _ in points)                                      
    x_min, x_max = min(x_coords), max(x_coords)                                 
    y_coords = tuple(y for _, y in points)                                      
    y_min, y_max = min(y_coords), max(y_coords)                                 
    # Calculate width and height of target area.                                
    w = x_max - x_min + 1                                                       
    h = y_max - y_min + 1                                                       
    # Create scaled surface with properties of target surface.                  
    s = pygame.Surface((w * scale, h * scale), 0, surface)                      
    s_points = [((x - x_min) * scale, (y - y_min) * scale)                      
                for x, y in points]                                             
    pygame.draw.polygon(s, color, s_points)                                     
    # Scale down surface to target size for supersampling effect.               
    s2 = pygame.transform.smoothscale(s, (w, h))                                
    # Paint smooth polygon on target surface.                                   
    surface.blit(s2, (x_min, y_min))
```

Feel free to point out errors, except that is uses quite a bit of resources, which is obvious.

**UPDATE**: The `smoothscale` function does not honour transparency, I will write a version that uses transparency when I'm on it again. You can use this function as a proof of concept meanwhile.